# What is the Private Beta?

Tags: discussion

I notice that there is badge for people that actively participate in the private beta. What is this thing? I tried searching on google and found some stackexchange links but they were not helpful. How can one participate in this thing?

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63401/what-is-private-beta-status

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proposed SE sites go through a testing process before they are admitted as full members of the SE network, to ensure they'll be active and have plenty of experts participating. The site where new proposals for SE sites are made, and the testing process is tracked, is called [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). Part of the process is the "private beta" stage, where those people who committed to using the site on Area 51 are allowed to start using the (still provisional) site. The level of participation determines whether it can proceed to "public beta" (where the site is still provisional, but anyone can use it), and also seeds the site with questions so it doesn't look like a ghost town during the public beta stage (if it does end up qualifying for it).

Comment: Thanks Zev. I understand this now.